# Alert issue - Geolocation using harvesine distance formula

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup, alert

I have been learning code with Coding for Dummies by Nikil Abraham.
In the book there is a project with the code included to develop an App for a restaurant to send an alert to a customer within a 5 - 10 min walk away from the restaurant with a coupon for the restaurant upon clicking on the check in button.

I have input all the code using html,  css and javascript via codepen and for some reason the alert will not pop up.

I have researched where i might be going wrong but I am really stuck.

Here is the code:

The Html:

```
<head>
<title>McDuck's App</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>McDuck's Local Offers</h1>

<button onclick="getLocation()">CheckIn</button>

<div id="geodisplay"/>
<div id="effect"/>


</body>
```

The Css:

```
body {
text-align: center;
background: white;
}

h1, h2, h3, p {
font-family: Sans-Serif;
color: black;
}

p {
font-size: 1em;
}
```

The javascript:

```
function getLocation() {
if (navigator.geolocation){
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showLocation);
}
}
```

//store location

```
function showLocation(position){
var mcduckslat=53.510207;
var mcduckslon=-6.399289;
```

//current location

```
var currentpositionlat=position.coords.latitude;
var currentpositionlon=position.coords.longitude;
```

// calculate the distance between current location and McDuck's location

```
var distance=getDistanceFromLatLonInMiles(mcduckslat, mcduckslon,    
currentpositionlat, currentpositionlon);

//displays the locaton using .inner.HTML property and the lat & long     
 coordinates from your current location

document.getElementById("geodisplay").inner.HTML="Latitude: " +      
currentpositionlat + "<br>Longitude: " + currentpositionlon;

 }

 //haversine distance formula

   function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
   var R = 6371; //Radius of earth in km
   var dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1); 
   var dLon = deg2rad(lon2-lon1);
   var a =
   Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + 
   Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) *                             
   Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) *     
   Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);

 var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a),
           Math.sqrt(1-a));
 var d = R * c * 0.372823; //Distance in miles                                        
 return d;
}

function  deg2rad(deg) {
  return deg * (Math.PI/180);
}

alert(distance);

if (distance < 0.5) {
 alert("You get a free meal");
}
else {
 alert("Thanks for checking in!");
}
```

Link to copepen
http://codepen.io/Saharalara/pen/Grxmmj

Comment: Did my answer help you at all? Click the link at the top of my answer to see the solution working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Here's the fiddle to see it working: https://jsfiddle.net/pnruje2g/6/

---

After tinkering with this for a bit, I have found 4 issues.

The first one is the deprecation of getCurrentPosition() in a non-HTTPS environment, like CodePen, in Google Chrome.

Here's the exact message I get in Google Chrome:

> getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no longer work on insecure
> origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your
> application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See
> https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins for more details.

You may want to try this in a different browser, if you're using Google Chrome. It does work on local sites though.

The next issue is calling the function `getDistanceFromLatLonInMiles()` which doesn't exist. I replaced it with a call to `getDistanceFromLatLonInKm()`.

The third issue is trying to assign a property that doesn't exist, you reference `inner.HTML` instead of `innerHTML`.

The fourth issue is the location of your alerts. Currently they are just sitting at the bottom of your JS file, not doing anything. We want to show the alerts once we have finished calculations. I moved your alerts to the end of the `showLocation()` function.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much for your help. Really helped me to understand so much more. I had a feeling there was an issue with the miles. Thanks again,  really appreciate it!